# Type-checking of Vue w/ Typescript but w/o Webpack/ts-loader

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, ts-loader

Since August 2018 it's possible to compile `Typescript` code with `Babel` and have type checking as a separate process.

I wonder if it is possible to do type checking of custom file formats like `.vue` with `<script lang="ts">` sections w/o `Webpack`/`ts-loader`? (I reckon in that case Typescript would need to support file preprocessing in order to be able to digest different file formats).

Right now I have to maintain a separate webpack configuration with `ts-loader` and compile Vue.js project, though all I need is to type-check it. So this approach looks more like a hack and overhead.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to use `ts-loader` with Webpack. Our Vue.js is extremely large-scale and we have multipage SPA with Webpack as our bundler. You don't really need to have a separate configuration for **ts-loader**. Have a look at our Webpack config (three instances of ts-loader):

```
const rules = [
    {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        include: [...PATHS.shared, path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        options: {
            transpileOnly: isDev,
            appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
            instance: 'common',
            configFile: path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json')
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        include: [PATHS.app1],
        options: {
            transpileOnly: isDev,
            appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
            instance: 'app1',
            configFile: path.join(PATHS.app1, 'tsconfig.json')
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        include: [PATHS.app2],
        options: {
            transpileOnly: isDev,
            appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
            instance: 'app2',
            configFile: path.join(PATHS.app2, 'tsconfig.json')
        }
    }
];
```

Coming back to your question, I have had success with `@babel/preset-typescript` but we do not use `.vue` files as [there are problems](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/4563) when processing `.vue` files. *Note: We set `transpileOnly` to false during development.*

If you can switch to using class syntax with `@Component` decorator and use [**vue-template-loader**](https://github.com/ktsn/vue-template-loader), then you can switch to using Babel + TypeScript. There are little nasty surprises like no support for [`const enums`](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6476), namespaces, etc.

> Note: Using `ts-loader` over `@babel/preset-typescript` has its own advantages. Coupled with Webpack, `ts-loader` is more hackable. If you need typed JSX i.e. TSX support with Vue.js, then babel route makes more sense. If you are using `.vue` files, then there is no considerable difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't answer my question.
As of the problems with processing `.vue` files by `@babel/preset-typescript` - I'm currently investigating if they are still in effect and how serious they are. Till now I haven't found any problems for my application

Comment: Thank you Harshal! Adding `appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],` to ts-loader solved an issue I have been fighting for days.  Not sure why that doesn't appear in other TypeScript+Vue+Webpack setups